# Smooth screen recording

Tags: video, screen-recorder

I'd like to make a video screencast. (Video only, no sound) 
What are the minimal system requirements to get it smooth? With my Lenovo S10-2 (Netbook) the final video is *stuttering*.

(Lenovo IdeaPad S10-2: Atom 1.6 GHz - 160 GB HDD / 5400 rpm - 10.1 in 1024 x 600 - 1 GB RAM - Windows XP)

Comment: Depends on what software you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to upgrade your hardware, or your software to make this work?

If software, I guess I'd just try a bunch of screencast software and see which gives you the best results.

Also, try fiddling with the quality settings (go lower) and capture area size (go smaller) to increase performance.

(I personally use Jing for simplicity)

Comment: Do you think my Netbook is fast enough to create a smooth recording without glitches and stuttering? (Lenovo IdeaPad S10-2: Atom 1.6 GHz - 160 GB HDD / 5400 rpm - 10.1 in 1024 x 600 - 1 GB RAM - Windows XP)

Comment: There is no way to know without actual testing I think...  What software are you using?